# Is it possible to check TempData inside if condtion in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I want to check `TempData` inside of `if` condition. But I am getting an error.

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Customer(PurchaseViewModel purchaseviewmodel)
{
    TempData["Fromdt"] = purchaseviewmodel.FromDate;
    TempData["todt"] = purchaseviewmodel.ToDate;
    If(TempData["Fromdt"] == Convert.ToDateTime(“01/01/0001”)&& TempData["todt"] == Convert.ToDateTime(“01/01/0001”))
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
    return View(Customer);
}
```

Why I am getting model values in Tempdata means I want to pass the values which I am getting in TempDate to another action . So only I am using TempData. Now I am getting error. The Error is

> Operator == is not applied between object and System.DateTime.

I tried my level best to explain the issue. So any one help me to resolve this issue. And I need TempData only not to store values directly in variable.  I can able to store the value in variable like

```
    var  fmdt = purchaseviewmodel.FromDate;
    var  todt = purchaseviewmodel. ToDate;
```

But my requirement to store values in TempData only that is my requirement because I need to use that TempData values in another  action.  I need for another purpose

Comment: Temp data stores and exposes an `object` so `==` wont work when tryin to compare to DateTime in your case. you need to cast the object exposed by TempData to do your comparison. ie: `Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001") == (DateTime)TempData["Fromdt"]`

Comment: That means u ask me to cast the tempdata value right

Comment: yes. you need to cast the exposed tempdata value

Comment: Then if(( Datetime)Tempdate["FromDate"] == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001))

Comment: based on what you are asking, that would be correct

Comment: Then if(( Datetime)Tempdate["FromDate"] == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001)) if I declare lik  this means it will work.. ??

Comment: Test it and find out.

Comment: OK I hava check and let you know within half an hour

Comment: Also no need to do convert to datetime. You can use `DateTime.MinValue` ie: `if(( Datetime)Tempdate["FromDate"] == DateTime.MinValue)`

Comment: Nikos you are correct  its working.  Thank  you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temp data stores and exposes an `object` so `==` wont work when trying to compare to `DateTime` in your case.

You need to cast the object exposed by TempData to do your comparison.

Also no need to convert the string to datetime. You can use `DateTime.MinValue`

```
if((Datetime)TempData["FromDate"] == DateTime.MinValue)
```